# What is this UPS communication IC?

Tags: usb, usb-device, ups

I'm looking inside an Inform brand UPS. On its communication board there are 6 chips. Four optocouplers, one NE555 timer and a mistery IC, pictured below. The communication board only has the USB-B populated, the DB-9 footprint is unused. On the mistery chip, I can make out the "RICHC" brand and four other strings: "RC-USB0100147", "1533N" and "BTS158E2". None of the strings allowed google to give me any hint about which company made it and what exactly this chip does (datasheet or at least some marketing brochure). Can you help?

[image: A chip marked "RICHC" "RC-USB0100147", "1533N" and "BTS158E2"]

Comment: run a USB cable from the UPS to your computer ... it may become apparent to you what is the chip's purpose

Comment: It is apparent. It's the "brains" of the thing. The UPS monitoring software reads voltages, load % and battery capacity from it.  I'd like more information that that, though.

Comment: probably custom made ... might be IO only ... the "brain` may be another IC ... might be a serial2usb converer

Comment: I described all the ICs on the comms board above. The only other board is the main board, with only a LM324N (four op-amps) and a KA3843 (PWM controller), apart from the power section transistors with the big radiators. I tend to agree with the "custom made" opinion, but the monitoring software seems very generic (UPSilon 2000 by MegaTec, http://www.megatec.com.tw/Download.htm ), and the mystery chip is not branded MegaTec or Inform, so a datasheet should be available somewhere...

Comment: I have one also socketed into a board with two network ports on it. One input and one output. The brand name on the chip is RICHCOMM which isn't much more help. I couldn't find the company. I was figuring that it was a PIC with proprietary code flashed to it but it is definitely the chip that translates the USB which is why I want to get pinouts for it. It has one dual op amp in its support circuit and is connected via a couple of optocouplers to a 4 pin PCB connector for signal and power. The network ports are completely independent of all of this and do nothing but route the network input po